# Help needed to choosing amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc

I am looking to  generate a moderate frequency sine wave around 1kHz with amplitude and dc offset control. I plan to use an Analog Discovery 2 tool to generate the sine wave (max 5V) and use an external power supply to boost it (to around 10V). I would be needing a summing amplifier for that.

My question is, should I choose an inverting or a non-inverting amplifier? For that frequency, any suggestions as to what model Op-amp to use?

Thank you.

Comment: no, you don't need a summing amplifier for that. You'd let the Analog Discovery 2 generate the (scaled down) signal *including* the offset and just amplify that.

Comment: Hello! May I ask how to amplify that? We need an opamp?